# mvc model binding and null checking

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple model as below

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string property1 {get;set;}
    public string property2 {get;set;}
}
```

On my razor view i have two textboxes thats mapping to these two properties. 
Only one of the text box is a required field and other one can be left empty.(that is either property1 or property2 can be entered or both can be entered..however both cannot be left blank)

My controller action method is quite simple

```
     public ActionResult MyMethod(TestModel tmodel)
     {
          //code fails on this null check..object reference not set to instance of object 
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmodel.property1))
          {
          }
      }
```

If i do this on my attribute of my model, the above statement works..why is null alone failing ?

```
 [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
```

What i dont understand is why is the string.IsNullOrEmpty fails?

Here is the view..

```
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.property1, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.property1, new { @class = "form-control"})
        </div>          
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.property2, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
         <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.property2, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
```

Thanks for your thoughts...

Comment: Can you please show the view?

Comment: The IsNullOrEmpty fails because you are checking tmodel.property1 for null, but it's tmodel thats null

Comment: Fails how? Do you get an error, the code inside the `if` block gets executed when it shouldn't? Do you get a NullReferenceException, in which case it isn't IsNullOrEmpty that fails?

Comment: I think it throws an exception `//code fails on this null check..object reference not set to instance of object`. It happens because the model is null itself. Does it happen when just one of the properties is empty?

Comment: before the isnullorempty check if i do, if (tmodel!=null), then that passes..so its the string.isnullorempty that fails...

Comment: Is this the entire view? Do you set what the model is in the view with `@model`?

Comment: Yes @Floremin i have set that..obviously its not the entire view but just the cut down version..If i enter the value in both the textbox, its correctly captured in my tmodel variable. So i know model binding works ....

Comment: So, you're saying (previous comment), you do something like `if (tmodel != null) { if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmodel.property1)) ... }` and it still fails on `string.IsNullOrEmpty` line, correct? If you put a breakpoint on that line and inspect `tmodel` what do you get?

Comment: Yes, Floremin, you are right..it fails only on the second if and not on the first if

Comment: when i examine under debug, tmodel property1 is null, while property 2 has a value that i entered in the textbox..

Answer (score 1):

-- EDIT --
To perform complex validation logic, implement `IValidatableObject` on your ViewModel:

```
public class TestModel : IValidatableObject {

    public string property1 {get;set;}
    public string property2 {get;set;}

     public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(property1) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(property2)) {
              yield return new ValidationResult(
                  "some error message", 
                  new[] { "property1", "property2"}
              );
         }
     }
}
```

Check the ModelState in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(TestModel tmodel) {
   if(!ModelState.IsValid) {
      // error handling here
   }              
}
```

Comment: I believe he doesn't want property1 as required, nor property2. Just both can't be empty.

Comment: Yes, i cant do the required like you had mentioned as either field can be empty...

Comment: Please see my edit that shows how to handle complex validation logic.

Comment: Georg i am not looking for a validation logic..my question is why is string.isnullorempty call fails ?

Comment: OK, I thought that would solve your underlying problem (check whether one of two inputs is empty) in a standard way. Did you inspect the POST data? Guess your string is not sent as null or string.Empty.

Comment: Thats what is confusing..upon inspecting in debug, property1 is null, but still  string.isnullorempty is failing...

Answer (score 0):

With this code, I guess that you'll never reach the string.IsNullOrEmpty code. But you have to show us the view to solve the real problem.

```
    public ActionResult MyMethod(TestModel tmodel)
    {
       if(tmodel != null)
       {
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmodel.property1))
          {
          }
       }              
   }
```

Comment: i have updated my code with the view...also..when i did the exact check that you did, it went through the first check, as in my case tmodel was not null

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(TestModel tmodel)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmodel.property1) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmodel.property2))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("property1", "The field property1 can only be empty if property2 is not");
                ModelState.AddModelError("property2", "The field property2 can only be empty if property1 is not");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("otherAction");   //or do whatever you want            
            }
            else
            {
                //back to form with the errors highlighted
                return View(tmodel);
            }
        }
```